# Angular Cli - Using external CDN paths for bundles

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using Angular Cli, how could the app index.html include resources like

```
<link href="//cdn.somecdnserver.com/styles.876a543b210c.bundle.css rel="stylesheet"/>
```

instead of using relative paths like

```
<link href="styles.876a543b210c.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

when doing ng build?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `--deploy-url` option to `ng build`. For instance:

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url //cdn.somecdnserver.com/
```

This will result in all style and script bundles to be referenced relative to `//cdn.somecdnserver.com/`.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I managed to add a gulp process after AngularCli bundling to replace paths.

And in the scripts of package.json I added "&& gulp" like

"scripts": {
      "build" : "ng build && gulp"
   }